# How to make a video where an actor writes facing the camera?

Tags: shooting, tutorial

I'd like to know how to produce this kind of instructional video, where an actor is writing on an invisible wall facing the camera:

*Introduction to Limits (mathbff)*

What equipment/tools and which setup is required to shoot this video?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a few simple things to do this:

1. a camera
2. a large piece of glass or plexiglass
3. dry erase markers
4. editing software capable of basic transform controls

Record your actor writing on the glass.  To the camera, the writing will appear backwards.  Use your editing software to flip the image horizontally.  The writing will now appear normal*.  Most editing software is capable of this operation.  If there's not a "flip horizontal" command, try setting the horizontal scale to -100%.

*Pro tip:  Make sure your actor's clothes don't have any writing on them, or it will appear backwards in the final result.

Comment: Or you can write with reflective font, if there are not lot of letters. With siple drawings it is not a problem at all.

Comment: Or if you want to do more fancy stuff like pixie dust as write is being generated, you can use tracking software and 3D effects to accomplish that.

Comment: Of note: The glass will probably reflect the equipment and crew. Make sure the actor and background is lit but everything else is not. Position the lights to the sides. Crew members may need to wear black body suits, and it may help to hang a black tablecloth or something similar behind the crew & equipment. Also have the performer wash his/her hands and not apply lotion before shooting, so they won't leave smudges on the glass.

Comment: When shooting into glass you can hang a black cloth  in front of the camera with just a hole for the lens. We do that when shooting into aquariums.